# How to convert JSON and store it in a variable?

Tags: json, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have JSON data in `.../arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/FeatureServer/0`.
I want to parse it and store it in a variable. For that I am using below code:

```
esri.request({  
        url:baseURL,   
        content:{f:"json"},  
        callbackParamName:"callback",  
        load:getServiceDetails,   
        error:esriConfig.defaults.io.errorHandler  
    });  

function getServiceDetails(response, args) {
    alert(response);
    var info = [];
    dojo.forEach(response.folders, function (folder) {
        info.push("Folder: " + folder + "<br/>");
    });
    dojo.forEach(response.services, function (service) {
        info.push("Service Details: " + service.name + " " + service.type + "<br/>");

    });
    console.log(info);
```

But `info` is empty. What is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2):

*I have modified this answer according to your specifications in comments below.*

What your code is trying to do, is to list all folders and services in your rest services repository folder. The url of that folder is your baseURL variable. The problem is that your baseURL variable is set to

```
http://yourserver/arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/FeatureServer/0
```

,and this actually is not address of a folder, but addrres of specific feature service. Feature services has different response parameters. The variables folders and services is pointless for service since it contains no folders nor services, but in this case feature description. For instance if you wish to query your feature class and know its attributes, keep your baseURL as it is and replace your forEach loops with

```
dojo.forEach(response.fields, function (field) {
        info.push("Field: " + field.name + "<br/>");
```

and you will get list with feature field names (should work, not tested).

But if your goal si to list all folders and services in your rest services repository, you have to change your baseURL to something like this:

```
http://yourserver/arcgisserver/rest/services
```

an your code should work.

**Hint:** You can allways check how your respons looks like when you type your url with `f=json` parameter into your browser. Like this:

```
http://yourserver/arcgisserver/rest/services?f=json
```

You will get a json response and you can check if desired attributes are contained.

Comment: you mean, your service is published throug arcgis online?

Comment: no.I means say is in arcgis community some one asked same question.For that above is correct answer they said.But why its not working for me

Comment: can you just provide a link to that question in arcgis forum?

Comment: I have modified my answer according to your comments.